# Preempting a thread that is executing synchronized method

Tags: java, thread-safety

Give the following code

```
    class Test{
       double x;
       public void synchronized a()
       { 
          x = 0;
          //do some more stuff
       }
       public void b() 
       { 
          x = -1; 
       } 
    }
```

Can the thread in a(), in the middle of modifying x be preempted by a thread that calls b() on the same object?

Isn't synchronized method be executed like one single atomic operation?

I believe the other way is possible(thread in b() can be preempted by the thread that calls a() on the same object since b() is not guarded my the Test object lock).

Can some one shed some light on this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`synchronized` only stops other threads from acquiring the same monitor. It in *no way* makes the operation atomic. In particular:

- Side-effects of the method can be observed by other threads which aren't trying to synchronize on the same monitor
- If an exception occurs, there's no sort of roll-back
- Other threads can access and modify the same data used by the synchronized method, if they aren't synchronized on the same monitor

`b()` isn't synchronized, so it's entirely possible for one thread to be executing `a()` and another to be executing `b()` at the same time.

Comment: Another problem which is not related the origin question is if a synchronized method need too much time to execute, can OS scheduler preempt it and switch to another thread? If possible, will this thread will release the lock?

Comment: @Richard: Nope, that won't release the lock. A synchronized method can take as long as it wants, and be pre-empted multiple times - nothing is going to be able to acquire that lock while the synchronized method has it. (Note that calling `wait()` releases the lock and reacquires it later though.)

Answer (score 0):

Since `b()` is not synchronized and `a()` is, it is possible for one thread to be in `a()` and the other to be in `b()`. So the value of `x` will most possibly be garbled due to parallel non-synchronized access to `x`.

In addition, if your code were like this:

```
class Test{
       double x;
       public void synchronized a()
       { 
          x = 0;
          //do some more stuff
       }
       public void b() 
       { 
          x = -1; 
          a(); //added call to a()
       } 
    }
```

and both of your threads are running on the **same instance** then there arises a possibility of Thread 1 [ currently in `a()` being preempted by Thread 2 [currently in `b()`].

However after Thread 1 is preempted, as Thread 2 tries to enter the `a()` method, the JVM will not allow it; since another thread [albeit a non running one] already has the lock on it. Hence now Thread 2 will be made to wait until Thread 1 completes execution of `a()` and returns. Then Thread 2 will [most probably] be brought back to life and allowed execution of `a()`.